# Почему не получается создать таблицу?

Tags: java, база-данных, h2

Доброй ночи. Скажите пожалуйста, кто нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой, что в БД *H2* не получается создать `TABLE` ?

**Собственно метод** :

```
public static void maketable(){
    Statement statement = null;
    try {
        statement = conn.createStatement();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        statement.executeQuery("CREATE TABLE SETTINGS_BACKUP (\n" +
                "                    PARAM CLOB,\n" +
                "                    VALUE CLOB\n" +
                "            )");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Exception** :

> База данных уже используется: null. Возможные решения: закрыть все другие соединения; использовать режим сервера.

Я конечно всё понимаю, но не понимаю одной вещи... Почему чтобы сделать обычную операцию в бд, обязательно всех отключать (и кстати не понятно как, а точнее какой командой?)? То есть если например в разгар рабочего дня мне надо будет через программу создать какой-то `TABLE`, то придётся отключать 10 клиентов от БД, чтобы они подождали, пока создастся `TABLE` и затем через какое-то заново подключать всех обратно на места? И как правило 2-4 клиента не переживёт таких махинаций и просто вылетит.

Comment: в каком месте возникает эта ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот такой код

```
public class H2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1", "", "");
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            st.execute("CREATE TABLE SETTINGS_BACKUP (PARAM CLOB, VALUE CLOB)");
            PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO SETTINGS_BACKUP (PARAM, VALUE) VALUES (?,?)");
            prep.setString(1, "a");
            prep.setString(2, "b");
            prep.executeUpdate();
            prep = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM SETTINGS_BACKUP");
            ResultSet rs = prep.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("PARAM " + rs.getBlob("PARAM") + " VALUE " + rs.getBlob("VALUE"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

У меня он работает без ошибок. Таблица создается и значения в нее попадают.